# (click) not working on anchor tag after implementing angular universal

Tags: angular, routes, click, angular-universal, universal

I have certain (click) on anchor tag that was used to perform functions like goBack, function print() for window.print().

For example,

```
<a (click)="onBackClicked()" class="btn-secondary-nav back">Go back</a>
```

They have stopped working after installing universal in my application.

onBackClicked function in component:-

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.previousRoute = this.routingState.getPreviousUrl();
    }
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
        //
    }
  }

    
onBackClicked = () => {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
          if (!this.forcedUrl) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(this.previousRoute);
          } else {
            this.router.navigate([this.forcedUrl.route], { queryParams: this.forcedUrl.queryParams });
          }
        }
      }
```

As shown above, I have made changes for the browser and server respectively.

Also, the value of `this.routingState.getPreviousUrl()` obtained from the following service is always '/',

```
export class RoutingStateService {
  private history = [];
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  public loadRouting(): void {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(({urlAfterRedirects}: NavigationEnd) => {
        this.history = [...this.history, urlAfterRedirects];
      });
  }


  public getHistory(): string[] {
    return this.history;
  }

  public getPreviousUrl(): string {
    return this.history[this.history.length - 2] || '/';
  }

}
```

Comment: So what is it that does not work?

Comment: function onBackClicked() is not called on anchor click

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with universal

Comment: It stopped working after I installed angular universal

Comment: Installing universal will have no impact on calling a component method from the template. Why is `onBarClicked` defined as an arrow function this and not `onBarClicked(){...}`?